# Compound Producer-Consumer in Java

Tags: java, producer-consumer

I have a relationship that must work as follows; thread A publishes some change to thread B, who takes that change and publishes it to thread C.

The problem is producer-consumer, and I have no problem using a BlockingQueue to implement it with only two entities. How can I make thread B a sort of hybrid producer and consumer to make this work? As in, is there some specified model to follow for problems in this genre?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two blocking queues: one between A and B; the other between B and C.

Comment: So, I should pass in two BlockingQueues into the constructor of B?

Comment: @CoconutJones - How you set it up depends on how your surrounding code is structured. It might set up by an external code and passed to the constructors for B (and C), or set up by B in its constructor, or by C. The only requirement is that the second queue is set up in such a way that B and C can both access it. Without seeing your code, it's hard to make any recommendation.